# Fill upper triangular matrix without loop in R

Tags: r, matrix, sapply

The objective is to fill the upper triangular matrix with the count calculate from the rating dataset. Each value is calculated and stored by finding the correct index. It is not stored sequentially.The below R code works perfectly, but takes too much time for large datasets.

```
ratings <- read.csv("ratings.csv", header=TRUE, sep=",")    
>> head(ratings)
  userId movieId rating  timestamp
1      1      16    4.0 1217897793
2      1      24    1.5 1217895807
3      1      32    4.0 1217896246
4      1      47    4.0 1217896556
5      1      50    4.0 1217896523
6      1     110    4.0 1217896150

no_nodes <- nrow(movies)*2
temp <- movies$movieId
nodes_name <- c(paste(temp,"-L",sep=""),paste(temp,"-D",sep=""))

ac_graph <- matrix(NA,nrow=length(nodes_name),ncol=length(nodes_name),dimnames = list(nodes_name,nodes_name))
for(i in 1:nrow(movies)){
  for(j in (i+1):nrow(movies)){
    ac_graph[which(nodes_name==paste(i,"-L",sep="")),which(nodes_name==paste(j,"-L",sep=""))] <- length(intersect(ratings[ratings$movieId==i&ratings$rating>2.5,1],ratings[ratings$movieId==j&ratings$rating>2.5,1]))
    ac_graph[which(nodes_name==paste(i,"-D",sep="")),which(nodes_name==paste(j,"-D",sep=""))] <- length(intersect(ratings[ratings$movieId==i&ratings$rating<=2.5,1],ratings[ratings$movieId==j&ratings$rating<=2.5,1]))
  }
}
```

Is it possible to do the same using apply,sapply, outer or some function?

Comment: You can use `ac_graph[upper.tri(ac_graph, diag=FALSE)] <-  vectorofvalues`  It s better to show a reproducible example.  Where is the `ratings` dataset?